# PHP and HTML to make nice interactive file display page

Tags: php, html

I've found a good demo code that I was able to make work with what I'm trying to do. But the final product is fairly ugly, and doesn't let me view the files. As far as the "nice" part goes, I have a feeling I should be looking as something more jquery oriented?

When i click on the link for a displayed file, I get a url not found error. The path to the file is incorrect...

This is incorrect and what the script currently tries to navigate to:

```
http://server/var/www/html/reports/1/Doe_John/2019-04-01/Run_2_Report.pdf
```

This is correct and works to display the file in the browser:

```
http://server/reports/1/Doe_John/2019-04-01/Run_2_Report.pdf
```

Is there a straightforward way to "subtract" out the extra file path portion that is causing the problem?  I had to add the {$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']} part to make it find the files, but that seems to be what is causing the issue now.

I'm also wanting to sort the files by date, and it's not doing that correctly. The dates are being sorted alphabetically by month. Can this be accomplished with just HTML, or should I again be looking at something like Jquery?

PHP that displays all pdf files in structure:

```
<?PHP
  // Original PHP code by Chirp Internet: www.chirp.com.au
  // Please acknowledge use of this code by including this header.

  //Test User Vars
  $region = "1";
  $first_name = "John";
  $last_name = "Doe";

  function getFileList($dir, $recurse = FALSE)
  {
    // array to hold return value
    $retval = array();

    // add trailing slash if missing
    if(substr($dir, -1) != "/") $dir .= "/";

    // open pointer to directory and read list of files
    $d = @dir($dir) or die("getFileList: Failed opening directory $dir for reading");
    while(false !== ($entry = $d->read())) {
      // skip hidden files
      if($entry[0] == ".") continue;
      if(is_dir("$dir$entry")) {
        $retval[] = array(
          "name" => "$dir$entry/",
          "type" => filetype("$dir$entry"),
          "size" => 0,
          "lastmod" => filemtime("$dir$entry")
        );
        if($recurse && is_readable("{$dir}{$entry}/")) {
          $retval = array_merge($retval, getFileList("{$dir}{$entry}/", TRUE));
        }
      } elseif(is_readable("$dir$entry")) {
        $retval[] = array(
          "name" => "$dir$entry",
          "type" => mime_content_type("$dir$entry"),
          "size" => filesize("$dir$entry"),
          "lastmod" => filemtime("$dir$entry")
        );
      }
    }
    $d->close();

    return $retval;
  }
?>

<h1>List PDF files with links</h1>

<table class="collapse" border="1">
<thead>
<tr><th>Name</th><th>Type</th><th>Size</th><th>Last Modified</th></tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?PHP
  $dirlist = getFileList("{$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']}/reports/{$region}/{$last_name}_{$first_name}/", TRUE);
  foreach($dirlist as $file) {
    if($file['type'] != "application/pdf") continue;
    echo "<tr>\n";
    echo "<td><a href=\"{$file['name']}\">",basename($file['name']),"</a></td>\n";
    echo "<td>{$file['type']}</td>\n";
    echo "<td>{$file['size']}</td>\n";
    echo "<td>",date('r', $file['lastmod']),"</td>\n";
    echo "</tr>\n";
  }
?>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: And do you expect us to convert the demo code to something working for you? Divide your problem into smaller problems and try to solve them by your own. Stackoverflow is not a code writing service ;)

Comment: I edited my post to be a little more clear about my questions for folks who don't infer meaning as much as I do. I tend to write out my thoughts and expect people to understand what I'm asking. Terrible character flaw.  XD  Mostly looking for some prods in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second link works because `/var/www/html/` is probably the DocumentRoot of your server, if you are using Apache, it is kind of the root of your application.

Comment: I had to add in the {$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']} to the file path in order to get it to work....but that seems to be biting me in the ass now by passing it to the <a href=\"{$file['name']}\">.  Am I understanding that right?

Comment: I don't think it is necessary, just point your anchor to `http://server/reports/1/...` and if it's not working, maybe there is a server problem?

Comment: You're right. I had a slash wrong when testing it last night. I was able to remove {$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']} and just use reports/{$region}/{$last_name}_{$first_name}/.  I had a forward slash in front of reports that was causing it to barf.  So that fixed the file display!  Thanks.